# Getting " 'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array" error even though data is a data.frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a cca model in R but it returns an error that the data is not a `data.frame`,

`cca1 <- cca(spec2 ~ ., t(env.hel))`

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula, data, na.action = na.pass, xlev = xlev) : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array
```

However, my data ***is*** a `data.frame`

```
str(spec2)
'data.frame':   4965 obs. of  131 variables:
```

When I run:

`cca0 <- cca(OMZspec2 ~ 1, t(env.hel))`

it returns the correct result!

Comment: `t` converts its argument to a matrix, so `t(env.hel)` is a matrix.  I think you should re-examine the help file for `cca`. The first argument appears to be a formula and formulas do not accept data.frames as arguments as far as I know.